# Create a custom View in Powerpoint

Tags: powerpoint

I want to add a new view, created by me, in Powerpoint (in addition to Normal View, Notes View, Slide Sorter, etc.)
My intention is to change the location and size of the notes panel in the normal view, to put it on the right side all across the screen, and to put the slide navigation panel on the bottom

Comment: I just want to add, that you can report your needs through the feedback app of Microsoft, so when many users want a feature it will be added to the product (in this case PowerPoint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, PowerPoint does not provide the ability to add or change a view until now.